# Why string.format?

Tags: c#, string.format

Why shouldn't we simply use

```
 string s=product.Name+" has been saved";
```

instead of:

```
string s=string.Format("{0} has been saved", product.Name);
```

Comment: Coz in the first case you missed a `space` after the product name

Comment: I tend to use it because you can put a lot of different data types in there, for example numbers without using .ToString ().  It just looks neater IMO

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/03/12/performance-quiz-1-of-a-series.aspx

Comment: @Andrew: Can you give an example for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that, no one say that you cannot. But mainly for readability, the second approach is prefered. It's even more obvious as soon as you concat more than 2 strings, it gets really messy, hard to read and mantain.

Comment: There is no performance advantage?

Comment: @Aparan go through this once http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/03/12/performance-quiz-1-of-a-series.aspx

Comment: @Aparan There actually should be an advantage if you have more than one variable to format.

Comment: @Aparan: the performance advantage is very irrelevant for the very most of the cases, readability impact is much more important to pick one or other approach.

Answer (score 4):

One naive reason would be that it helps to prevent exactly the string formatting issue that you've presented in your *original* (unedited) question i.e.

```
string s=product.Name+"has been saved";
```

requires an extra space. The format method aids readability.

Answer (score 3):

If you have many strings that you want to add, each `+` operation create new string.

For adding many strings you can use `StringBuilder Class` or `String.Format`